# What does %\/ do (zsh prompt expansion)?

Tags: zsh

What does the sequence `%\/` do in zsh prompt expansion? `man zshmisc` doesn't contain the string `%\`, which is where the rest of the prompt-specific expansions are.

The sequence can be seen in [Holmans dotfiles](https://github.com/holman/dotfiles/blob/master/zsh/prompt.zsh):

```
directory_name(){
  echo "%{$fg_bold[cyan]%}%1/%\/%{$reset_color%}"
}

export PROMPT=$'in $(directory_name)› '
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%\` does nothing so is useless. Same for the `$` in `$'...'`. No need for it since there's no escape sequence to expand there.

The whole thing can be written:

```
PS1='in %{$fg_bold[cyan]%}%1//%{$reset_color%}› '
```

or:

```
PS1="in %{$fg_bold[cyan]%}%1//%{$reset_color%}› "
```

to have the `$fg_bold...` expanded at the time of that assignment rather than at each prompt.

No need to do the command substitution at each prompt since the output of `directory_name` doesn't change from one run to the next.

You probably don't want to `export` PS1 or PROMPT either.